# GIT: ¿cómo conectar un repositorio local nuevo con un repositorio en GitHub existente?

Tags: git, github

Estoy aprendiendo a manejar los repositorios GIT y aunque me está costando bastante, he logrado entender los conceptos básicos. He realizado varias pruebas con éxito, dentro de un entorno virtual con django 2.0; clonar en local un repositorio creado en github y subir archivos modificados en local con `add`, `commit` y GitHub Desktop o `"git push origin master"`.

Ahora intento hacer otra prueba: he creado una nueva carpeta local, he agregado los archivos del site-web, he modificado algunos y he creado un repositorio con GIT GUI (supongo que es lo mismo que `git init`).Intento clonar otra vez el repositorio de GitHub con estos resultados:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git
fatal: destination path 'LibrosWeb' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

El repositorio GitHub sólo tiene la rama maestra por defecto y no he incluido ningún colaborador para poder hacer las pruebas tranquilamente.

Entonces, ¿cómo conecto el repositorio local modificado con un repositorio existente en GitHub?

Estos son algunos enlaces interesantes que estoy siguiendo:

https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Fundamentos-de-Git-Trabajar-con-Remotos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAOI-Pi55e8&list=PLCKuOXG0bPi1XDpLnry3uqStf5g8F2O-u

Answer (score 5):

En el nuevo repositorio local tienes que añadir un remote, el nombre que se utiliza por defecto en git es "origin" pero podria ser cualquier otro:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git
```

Ahora que ya tienes el remote, puedes hacer git fetch para descargar los objetos y ramas remotos:

```
git fetch
```

Tu repositorio local aun no ha modificado ningún archivo, pero ahora ya tiene los objetos y referencias del remote y está preparado para ello.

Ahora "para sincronizar" la rama master de tu repositorio inicial, puedes hacer un checkout de la rama master del remoto. Pero git rechazará sobreescribir cualquier contenido local existente. Entonces, si tienes contenido nuevo, tienes varias opciones:

1. Crear una rama local (**git branch nombrerama**), checkout a ella (**git checkout nombrerama**) y hacer un commit de tus cambios actuales a ella. Posteriormente podrás integrar esta rama en la rama master.
2. Utilizar git stash save -u (guarda los cambios localmente, incluyendo archivos no seguidos (-u), pero sin crear ninguna rama, luego puedes recuperarlos).

Despues de esto ya puedes hacer el checkout de la rama remota master en tu rama local master (aún no deberías tener ninguna rama, ya que sólo has hecho git init y ningún commit)

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

Ahora ya puedes modificar lo que quieras, hacer commits locales y cuando lo decidas, enviarlos mediante push al repositorio master:

```
git push master
```

Si habías guardado antes los cambios locales, necesitas usar **git stash apply** (si utilizaste git stash) o **git merge nombrerama** (si utilizaste una nueva rama). Prefiero no explicarlo aquí para no complicar más las cosas.

Por último, el repositorio original habrá quedado por detras de éste, para sincronizarlo, deberas hacer:

```
git pull
```

git pull equivale a un git fetch seguido de git merge.

Comment: Edito:  he puesto por error git add remote y no lo correcto, que es: git remote add.

Comment: Pues no me funciona así. Esto es lo que hecho:
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Asi que no hice add ni commit. 
Después git remote add origin https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git (push)
y por último:
$ git push -u origin https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git

Comment: Me equivoqué con el push. Ahora lo puse bien pero tampoco funciona:
$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes . . . . .

Comment: Edito la respuesta porque no me había explicado bien. Ese error te lo da porque estas intentando actualizar el repositorio remoto, con un repositorio local que va "por detrás" del remoto, se puede hacer en ciertos casos utilizando --force, -f , pero en tu caso lo correcto es lo que te indico en la respuesta actualizada, saludos.

Comment: mzcarlos, he probado todo esto y nada funciona. Explico por pasos el proceso:
$ git log
commit e61b038a721be5b4ebd89438fee346399bce121c (HEAD -> master)
Author: Frank <frank_mascarell@gandiweb.com editor = notepad>
Date:   Fri Mar 16 21:51:50 2018 +0100

    Nueva versión con entorno virtual

Hay un commit de cuando inicié el repositorio.

Comment: Después:
$ git fetch
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 83, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
remote: Total 83 (delta 16), reused 80 (delta 16), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (83/83), done.
From https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Aquí no sé si creó una nueva rama o lo está recomendando que lo haga.

Comment: $ git stash save -u
No local changes to save

$ git checkout -b master origin/master
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.

$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

Comment: $ git push origin master
To https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Es posible que el problema sea lo siguiente: el repositorio remoto (GitHub) tiene una rama maestra que sigue apuntando al anterior repositorio local de mis pruebas. Si éste es el problema, ¿puedo hacer que además apunte al nuevo repositorio local y cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que haré unos comentarios necesarios referentes a git.
Para muchos desarrolladores que no necesitan de un equipo de desarrolladores, como es mi caso, el uso de git es innecesario. El control de versiones se puede administrar fácilmente con simples copias de seguridad locales, y subir al hosting la necesaria mediante algún protocolo suministrado por el proveedor de servicios.

Comment: Ahora, estoy investigando los posibles hosts para Django que no requieren de git, como Heroku, Digital Ocean, PythonAnyware, parece que necesitan git para poder trabajar. ¿Alguna sugerencia? o ¿Algún otro proveedor posible?

Aprovecho para dar las gracias a mzcarlos por su gran ayuda.

Aquí hay más detalles sobre el tema:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373080/git-how-to-connect-a-second-local-repository-with-an-existing-github-repository

Comment: @FrankMascarell: git (o cualquier otro sistema de control de versiones) es muy útil incluso en situaciones como la tuya en la que trabajas tú sólo. Es cierto que se necesita aprender su uso, y puede desesperar un poco al principio, pero creeme que merece la pena. Te sugiero que sigas trabajando como hasta ahora y poco a poco sigas investigando y aprendiendo un poco de git. Si te lees el libro progit desde el principio, con calma, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2  te acabarás haciendo con ello. Sobre los hosts para django, sin git no te puedo ayudar. Saludos!